# redis deployment on Kubernetes with sentinel

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I am deploying Redis and a sentinel architecture on Kubernetes.

when I work with deployments are my cluster that requires redis all is working fine.

the problem is that some services of my deployment are located on a different kubernetes cluster.

when the clients reach the redis sentinel ( which I exposed via NodePort that maps internally to 26379) they get an reply the master IP.

that actually happens is that they are getting the redis Master kubernetes IP and the internal port 6379. 
as I said while working in KUbernetes that works fine since the clients can access that IP but when the a services are external it is not reachable.

I found that there is a configuration named:
cluster-announce-ip and cluster-announce-ip

I have set those values to the external IP of the cluster and the external port hoping that it will solve the problem but still no change.

I am using the formal docker image : redis:4.0.11-alpine

any help would be appreciated